# can't install pandas0.25.0 with python 3.9

Tags: pandas

I want to install pandas0.25.0 on container python 3.9.

My docker image is: python:3.9

and i got this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, 
os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fndbv0q1/pandas_a819631e88d54e8f8fddfd0324875565/setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fndbv0q1/pandas_a819631e88d54e8f8fddfd0324875565/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) 
else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hgxej7_6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/pandas Check the logs for full command output.
```

How should i do please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can.

Only from release 1.1.3 does pandas support Python 3.9.

Here is the changelog where Py3.9 support was added:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.3.html